# Can't get fstream to read allocate an array size

Tags: c++, vector, struct, fstream

I'm trying to use a void function to read from a text file and allocate the size of a vector struct.
This is my void function.

```
void allocateFlight( ifstream &inFile, string &item,vector<Flight>&flight, int &i){

    inFile.open("reservations.txt");

    //check for error

    if (inFile.fail())
    {

        cerr << "Error Opening File" << endl;

        exit(1);

    }

    while (inFile >>item)
    {   
       
        i = 0;
        flight.resize(i);
        if (item.size() == 3){

            i++;
            flight.resize(i);
            
        }

    }
}
```

This is kept in a separate cpp file and in my main file I declared my variables and tried calling it but I'm only getting zero when I try to compile.

```
string item;
int i;
fstream inFile;

//this is the flgiht array to partition the amount of flights based on the first line of text indexing
std::vector<Flight> flight; 

int main(){

//pass by reference to allocateFlights
allocateFlight(inFile, item ,flight, i);

//int numFlights;


cout << flight.size();
```

I'm stumped trying to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: "I'm only getting zero when I try to compile" - did you mean when you try *running* the program? The size should be 1 if you read a 3-character input string and 0 otherwise. Is not this what you are getting?

Comment: What does the file actually look like, and what should the vector look like after the file is read? The code shown is clearing the vector on every string that is read, is that what you really want?

Comment: Yes that is when I'm trying to run it. This was my bad for not explaining what the txt format was.  I was trying to write a void function to find any 3 digit number which would be a flight number. The text file contains names and flight numbers in 3 digit format. Once a 3 digit number was found, it would add i by 1 until the end of file.

Comment: This is only first step. My intention is to use the void function to only allocate the size of the vector struct based on the amount of flights there are in the .txt file. After that I will be creating another loop that reads information on the actual flights into the vector.

Comment: infile seems like it should be local to allocateFlight